# guard not compiling changes to .sass file - Readline installed

Tags: ruby, osx-mountain-lion, readline, guard

I am having a problem with guard compiling changes to a .sass file

Guard will only update when I run the --clear command.

when I type 'guard' it responds with

16:36:38 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
16:36:38 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '***PATH TO PROJECT***'

I did follow the guide on the wiki for install readline properly ( https://github.com/guard/guard... ) still no success

project folder contains a sass directory with 1 .sass file (buttons.sass) and a css directory(created when running --clear from terminal) with one css file buttons.css(generated when running --clear from terminal while using guard)

I have looked around and people said to install readline, I did so and it didn't make any different I also tried running guard as root (sudo guard) to eliminate that possibility and still same result.

I have installed the latest version on ruby(2.0.0) using macports as well,